# Testing unauthorized pages with zope test browser

Tags: plone, zope

What's the correct procedure to check in the functional test case whether or not the page is accessible by the currently logged in user?

Please point a working example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if the page IS accessible is easy. You typically do

```
browser.open(url)
```

and check for something in browser.contents.

To make sure the page is inaccessible and for instance raises, you could import HTTPError

```
from urllib2 import HTTPError
```

obtain a browser instance, login with it, and do

```
self.assertRaises(HTTPError, browser.open, url)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am having hard time though, as Zope 2 is raising some exception, not HTTPError, which is not even based on Exception base class and catching it with try: except Exception,e: fails... aaaarg <_<

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> browser.handleErrors = False
>>> browser.open(unauthorized_url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Unauthorized: ...
```